# How is it possible to import one class into another with TypeScript/Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two classes that require a link between the two. How would I import one class into another from seperate files, instead of me having to re-declare each class within the linked class.

Here is my one class:

```
export class Box {
    Id?: number;
    Serial: string;
    PackDateTime: string;
    BatchNumber: string;
    Quantity: number;
    UserId: number;

    User: User; // This class is undefined as it cannot see the user class which is in a different file. 
}
```

My other class:

```
export class User {
    Id?: number;
    Name: string;
    Surname: string;
    Username: string;
    Password?: string;
    IsAdmin?: boolean;

    Boxes: Box[]; // Also needs a link to the Box class.
}
```

I tried importing the classes but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the import code you used?

Comment: `import { Box } from 'box.class';` All the classes are in the same foldler. But this gives a error that it cant find the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still looking for this answer this worked for me:

```
import { Arm } from './member.class'; // Arm class is in the same folder as BodyClass
import { Leg } from './card.class'; // Leg class is in the same folder as BodyClass

export class Body {
    Id: number;
    Name: string
    LegId: number;
    ArmId: number;

    Leg: Leg;
    Arm: Arm;
}
```

Comment: can u really name files .class and not ts?

Comment: TypeScript places the extensions on the end. It expects only TypeScript files to be imported

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that you have a circular dependency as `User` needs `Box` but it needs `User`.
You can't do that.

If both classes need the other then you need to put them in one file.

---

#### Edit

Another option is to have an interface in one file:

```
interface IBox {
    Id?: number;
    Serial: string;
    PackDateTime: string;
    BatchNumber: string;
    Quantity: number;
    UserId: number;

    User: User;
}

export class User {
    Id?: number;
    Name: string;
    Surname: string;
    Username: string;
    Password?: string;
    IsAdmin?: boolean;

    Boxes: IBox[]; // Also needs a link to the Box class.
}
```

And then pass the actual instance from the box to a user instance.

Comment: You could also just store the box ids in the user: `BoxIds: string[]` and get the boxes when you need them from a service or store which stores all box entities

Comment: Check my revised answer, I added another option